# SpringBoot - Multimodule projet & datasources - Unable to scan @Entity.class

Tags: spring-boot, entity, multi-module, multiple-databases

I have some trouble to configure my multimodule projet with multiple datasources. So, I need your help.

I have allready try :
[Springboot multimodule project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50044126/springboot-multimodule-project)
[SpringBoot ComponentScan issue with multi-module project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587377/springboot-componentscan-issue-with-multi-module-project)
[SpringBoot scanBasePackages not working in multi module project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51404923/springboot-scanbasepackages-not-working-in-multi-module-project)
And https://mhdevelopment.wordpress.com/2014/09/16/how-to-configure-spring-boot-with-jpa-and-multiple-projects/

But nothing work, i have the same issue.

So, that m'y multi-module classpath:

- BusinessModule, that include repositories and Entities:
  base package : **com.mycompany.business**.
  In that module, i have an external dependency where we can found @Entity class ( package : **com.mycompany.model**)
- RestModule, that are used to use BusinessModule.
  base package : **com.mycompany.rest**

## Business configuration

**Configuration for datasources**

*First data source*:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory", 
basePackages = {
        "com.mycompany.business.repository", "com.mycompany.model" })
@PropertySource(value = 
"file:${CPROCESS_INSTALL}/server/custom_config/datasources.properties")
public class BusinessDbConfig {

@Primary
@Bean(name = "dataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "business.datasource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Primary
@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
            .packages("com.mycompany.business.model", "com.mycompany.model")
            .persistenceUnit("business").build();
}

@Primary
@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
        @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
}
}
```

*Second data source*:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "barEntityManagerFactory",     transactionManagerRef = "barTransactionManager", basePackages = {
    "com.mycompany.bonita.repository" })
@PropertySource(value =     "file:${CPROCESS_INSTALL}/server/custom_config/datasources.properties")
public class BonitaDbConfig {

@Bean(name = "barDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "bonita.datasource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean(name = "barEntityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean barEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier("barDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.mycompany.bonita.model")
            .persistenceUnit("bar").build();
}

@Bean(name = "barTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager barTransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("barEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory barEntityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(barEntityManagerFactory);
}

}
```

**Repository configuration**

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface CDocumentRepository extends JpaRepository<CDocument, Long> {

@Query("select dp from CDocument d where d.persistenceid = ?1")
public CDocument findByPersistenceId(Long persistenceId);
}
```

**Entity**

```
@javax.persistence.Entity(name = "CDocument")
@Table(name = "CDOCUMENT") 
public class CDocument{ ... }
```

## **Rest module configuration**

**App configuration**

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= {"com.mycompany"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.mycompany")
@EntityScan("com.mycompany")
@Import({ BonitaDbConfig.class, BusinessDbConfig.class })
public class RestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(RestApplication.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(RestApplication.class, args);

}
}
```

**My controller**

```
@RestController
public class CreateSpaceController {
private CDocushareConnectRepository cDocushareConnectRepository;
private CDocumentRepository cDocumentRepository;
private DocumentRepository          documentRepository;
private CustomtableRepository       customTableRepository;
private CFieldsMappingRepository    cFieldsMappingRepository;

public CreateSpaceController(CDocumentRepository cDocumentRepository) {
    super();
    this.cDocumentRepository = cDocumentRepository;

}
...
}
```

When i try to start test or app, i have this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.mycompany.model.CDocument
```

I don't know why... Any help ?

Comment: did you annotate `CDocument` with `@Entity`?

Comment: Yes i did it:
    @javax.persistence.Entity(name = "CDocument")
    @Table(name = "CDOCUMENT")
    public class CDocument{
    ...
    }

Comment: Seems like your `@EntityScan` doesn't reach your entity. Try `@EntityScan(CDocument.class)`

Comment: I have the same error...
I think it's a scanning's problem, but i don't how i can debug it